# I ask coworkers to communicate in writing, but some ignore my request. What can I do?

Tags: professionalism, software-industry, communication, disability

Sometimes I ask people to communicate in written. i.e. something like:

> due to a neurological condition that I have, written communication works much better for me".

Neurological problems that I have sometimes make talking and understanding speech difficult to me, especially when talking is about complex things. We all are working remotely anyway, so why not? But some people simply ignore my requests and insist on making a voice call, or keep on talking if we're in the call already.

What's the best way to deal with such situations and don't make myself looking "uncooperative", "bad team player", etc?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133393/discussion-on-question-by-user855286-i-ask-coworkers-to-communicate-in-writing).

Comment: what is the exact phrasing you used to make your "requests"?

Comment: @aaaaasaysreinstateMonica mods deleted it from comments, so I added it to the post.

Answer (score 17):

Other employees are not obligated to adhere to your preferences, so if you present your disability as forming a mere preference, that's what will happen.

If you need special accommodations at work, you should speak with your manager. You can work with your manager to develop strategies to help you work effectively with your disability.

This may include the provision of therapy to help you better handle spoken conversations. Note that therapy does not necessarily mean you are cured of your disability. It means that you may be better equipped to handle the symptoms of your disability.

A solution your employer may also include is things like the de-provisioning of your phone, or whatever other mechanism is used for voice communication. An employer may also make workplace mandates that others are bound to follow.

When you have a disability in the workplace, it's not sufficient to attempt to change fellow employees to accommodate your needs. It's something that needs to be managed with your employer in a professional manner. There are many complex factors at play that need to be handled. If you choose to not involve your employer, and instead attempt to manage things in an ad-hoc manner an an individual basis with employees, you can expect sub-optimal results.

Before you go to your manager, it would be good to go to your doctor and get a written statement from them. This should help your employer better understand your disability.

Comment: It sure can be presented that way.

Comment: +1 The OP is asking their colleagues to bear the cost of writing down the information they would prefer to talk about.  Some people will de-prioritise this in favour of more urgent (or less onerous) tasks, unless it's made clear to them that they have to do it.

Comment: This answer is wrong in so many ways. 1) it's not "a bit harsh" (and as it turned out in the chat conversation, the author didn't write it in good faith - his only goal was to "prove" that I'm a pretender) 2) in fact the company *is* obligated to follow the law wrt reasonable accommodations, and employee are obligated to follow the rules of the company 3) something what I can't do well due to my disability is not a question of "preference" 4) involving my manager into communication with coworkers too often is a recipe for disaster 5) no "therapy" can fix a disability

Comment: @DaveGremlin so, your suggestion is that polite requests don't work and I have to flex my muscles

Comment: @user855286 If you're not willing to treat this disability with the due respect of formalising with your employer, I don't see why you would expect others to change their behaviour.

Comment: @GregoryCurrie what about ethics? Apparently, this concept doesn't exist for you.

Comment: @user855286 It's not your place to get into ethical arguments with your co-workers.

Comment: @GregoryCurrie you aren't my coworker. You wanted a reason why people could treat disability with the due respect, and I gave you one - ethics.

Comment: @user855286 Ethics is subjective. We can't expect everyone to have the same degree of understanding of the severity and impact of your disability.

Comment: @GregoryCurrie tell me about ethics that lets you treat disability without any degree of respect.

Comment: @user855286 By definition, ethics is subjective. I'm not seeing anything to suggest they are not treating disability without any degree of respect. But even if they are acting totally unethically that is not actionable. Which is why you should work with your employer rather than trying to understand the motivations behind your fellow employees.

Comment: You didn't answer the question that was actually asked. "rather than trying to understand the motivations behind your fellow employees." - being a bull in china shop is another recipe for disaster.

Answer (score 10):

As someone with a hidden/ unseen disability (memory problems), I also often require things in written, rather than verbal format so that I have something to refer to when I'm being given a task to work on, etc.

I don't know what country you are living/ working in, but in the UK, employers are required by law to make 'reasonable adjustments' to support any employees who have a disability/ learning difficulty, etc.

It can be difficult to ensure that you get this support (the 'reasonable adjustments'), even  when you have made your employer aware that you have these difficulties up front during your interview & again on your first day, and have also spoken to your manager about it. Sometimes they forget/ are too busy to do exactly what you would like them to.

A couple of points I would recommend doing from a practical perspective:

1. Ask to speak to your line manager in confidence. Explain the difficulties that your neurological problems cause you, and suggest alternate ways of working that might make things easier for you.
   Word of advice here - make sure you have a list of things you will try to do to make things easier for yourself. If you head into this conversation with a list of things you want your manager/ others to do for you, rather than approaching it as a collaborative thing, where both you and they have things that you'd like to do differently, then it may come across as being lazy/ unwilling to learn to do what's required/ work in the way the company want.
2. Always have a pen & notebook handy. When anyone phones, make notes on what they're saying/ what actions they're expecting you to take as a result of the call. At the end of the call, repeat the headlines of the notes you've taken back to them, along with what actions you are going to do, and ask them to confirm that you've got it all.
3. After a phone call, if you're unsure that you've remembered/ understood everything you need in order to do whatever you've been tasked to, or there are gaps in the notes you've taken, follow it up with an email/ Teams message to the person you were speaking to, recapping everything you have remembered, and ask them if there was anything else they mentioned/ anything you've missed.

Some points I would recommend doing from a 'professional life' perspective:

1. Speak to the doctor/ health professional you see regarding your neurological problems and ask them to provide a written letter which you can give to your employer/ manager explaining the difficulties these can cause you, and what can be done practically to support you & help you overcome these difficulties.
2. If you don't have one already, ask your doctor/ health professional to refer you to an Occupational Therapist - they specialise in supporting people with disabilities/ learning difficulties, and in ensuring that they are given the required support in the workplace. Get your Occupational Therapist to recommend how the difficulties you face can be overcome.
3. If you are not already, consider (and speak to your doctor/ health professional about) whether you should be registered as 'disabled' because of your neurological problems - being registered 'disabled' will give you certain rights in law, which will require your employer to meet the needs that your disability causes.

Comment: Note the important point in this answer, informing your employer of your disability. Which is different than saying to fellow employees "I'd prefer you not call me"

Comment: I was looking for this part of the answer and finally found it: email them back with your understanding of the issue.  If they don't write, then you write instead.  Then it's on them to correct your understanding, if it is not complete or correct.

Answer (score 6):

You mention that "some" people ignore such requests and call you anyways. This means that some other do write you instead of calling. This is good, and this suggests that the ones refusing to write may be more difficult/problematic coworkers that need a more explicit request.

I asked you how were you asking for this request and you replied: *"due to the neurological condition that I have, written communication works much better for me"*.

The thing is, if we parse this like a compiler, you are actually *not* requesting them to write you, you are "just" saying that written "works best for you"... perhaps you need to be more explicit, as we can see some coworkers are not getting your polite, more assertive, approach. An explicit phrasing would be something like:

> Hello John, nice to talk to you. Perhaps last time I was not clear enough, but I have a neurological condition that makes it difficult for me to have these conversations in speech. Please, send me an email instead. Thanks.

In short, perhaps you need to be more explicit when requesting people to email you instead of calling.

On a final note, I must make the observation that it may not be realistic to expect *everyone* to email you about *all* topics. Yes, emails are great for some stuff, but they also are slower, tend to go back and forth, may be noisy and difficult to read a long email thread, and sometimes may be an overkill for questions like *"hey, was the new button to be green or blue?"*.

Do keep this in mind in future interactions, and consider making an effort to realize that you may eventually have to have a conversation in speech. It's not like you can avoid speech forever... although I imagine this situation is difficult to you.

Comment: "Yes, emails are great for some stuff, but they also are slower, tend to go back and forth" - we have the text chat app for this kind of matters.

Comment: "An explicit phrasing would be something like" - let's assume that they ignore this request too. What's next?

Comment: @user855286 great, the chat app is perfect for those. Regarding the second question, if they ignore that, even though you explicitly told them about that, then I would consult my manager what else can I do

Comment: Ok will keep that in mind if I ever need it.

Answer (score 3):

> What's the best way to deal with such situations and don't make myself
> looking "uncooperative", "bad team player", etc?

**Stop answering the phone.** Let the call go to voicemail as needed.

Follow up with an email or text something like "Sorry I missed your call, but due to the neurological condition that I have, written communication works much better for me". Then follow up in writing.

> We all are working remotely anyway, so why not?

Note that for some people it's much more effective to communicate via a single phone call than to ping pong questions and answers back and forth in writing. It often gets things accomplished much more efficiently. So use this "don't answer the phone" technique only as often as necessary.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133394/discussion-on-answer-by-joe-strazzere-i-ask-coworkers-to-communicate-in-writing).

Answer (score 2):

It may take quite some time for your coworkers to remember that they should email you as well as or instead of calling. I recommend that you cheerfully and politely remind them about it, every time.

If you're able to extract any information from the phone call (or however the verbal conversation is happening) you can include it in the reminder. Examples:

> Yes, I can take care of that for you today or tomorrow. I need you to email me the [numbers, lists, urls, whatever] so I can see them.

or perhaps

> I think that might be something for me though I can't be sure until I see the [whatevers] and I can't process those verbally. Please email them to me and I'll reply right away to confirm that it's me or tell you who it is.

or even

> Sorry, that stream of [whatevers] is too much for me to process verbally. Drop me an email and I'll take a look at it right away. Do you want me to email you or call you once I know if I am the right person for the request and how long it will take?

Do not say "as you should know" or "as I have told you before" or "I hope you remember" or any of that. Perhaps this person knows you can't handle 6 pieces of information verbally but thought you could handle 4. Perhaps they just forgot that you actually can't process verbal requests rather than simply preferring written communication. Doesn't matter. You don't need to settle that, educate them, extract an apology from them for starting with the wrong modality, or apologize for needing a different modality. You don't need to discuss previous times they've asked for things or future times, either. The whole thing can be dealt with in a few seconds.

Tell them what you need and (since people typically call because they want a synchronous response) confirm what response you'll be providing as well. Do it with a smile.

Some coworkers will learn, skip the call, and go straight to the email. Others won't, either because they don't remember or because they have needs too (like the need for a response) and sending email doesn't meet those needs for them. That's cool. Any given pair of [you/coworker] will have a slightly different communication pattern that works for you both.

Speaking for myself, if you say more than about 4 numbers to me I forget all of them. And this is especially true if some are just names ("we could get the 302, it has 40 x'es, or the 709 which only has 30 but they're 50% bigger") kind of thing. With those I work with regularly, I just hold my hands up and say "Numbers numbers numbers! Email me a summary, please" and people do. With a stranger it would be more like "I can't hold all those numbers in my head from just hearing them, please email me a summary." This has worked for me for decades.

Comment: "cheerfully" - that's basically impossible when you have major depression.

Comment: That does make it harder. But what I mean is "not argumentatively", "not sullenly", "not with a reminder that you asked them this 5 times in the last 17 months", "not angrily" and so on. As cheerfully as you can.

Comment: What if I make a request like this and they _immediately_ ignore it and keep on talking?

Comment: Has that happened, or are you just worrying it might? I would probably reply something like "I can't process that verbally. If you want it to be done, please do email me." I say probably because depending on the person, and their relative rank to me, I might put in either a mild rebuke ("I just told you I need it in email") or an apology for not being able to do something they clearly want me to do ("I'm sorry if it's extra work for you,"

Comment: Yes, it did happen.

Answer (score 1):

The right time to ask them is when they call you. Get a phone call, pick up, find out who is calling, and explain to them at that moment. Not only what you want, but also *why*. Maybe have the text for an email prepared, so you can send an email at that moment, and ask them to check their emails before they continue.